# How to execute a command line from php

Tags: php, command-line

I need to convert the html file into PDF, I am having command line for this process

```
C:\Program Files\Software602\Print2PDF/print2pdf.exe /iniconvert C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/BPO/Praveen/OCT_08/html_files/file.ini
```

This is the command line to convert. But i dont know how to run this in php.

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use backticks: `` ` ``, you can use the [`exec`](http://php.net/exec) function, the [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) function or the [`system`](http://php.net/system) function.

be sure to correctly sanitize your params ([`escapeshellargs`](http://php.net/escapeshellargs), [`escapeshellcmd`](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd)). all of the above will not work in php’s [safe mode](http://php.net/safe_mode) though

Comment: Don't forget to enclose paths with spaces in double-quotes, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`system`](http://php.net/system) function but you will require a PHP version which allows it: impossible in safe mode.